# AWS ECS by terraform giving 504 and 503

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have set up a basic express app for deployment on AWS ECS Fargate, using a simple dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18.0-alpine

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

with the following terraform file:

```
terraform {
    required_providers {
      aws = {
        source = "hashicorp/aws"
        version = "~> 4.0"  
          }
    }
}

provider "aws" {
    region = "eu-west-2"
    access_key = "XXXXX"
    secret_key = "XXXXX"
}


resource "aws_ecr_repository" "prod_ecr_repo" {
  name = "prod-ecr-repo"
}

resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "prod_ecs_cluster" {
  name = "prod-ecs-cluster"
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "prod_ecs_task" {
  family                   = "prod_ecs_task" 
  container_definitions    = <<DEFINITION
  [
    {
      "name": "prod_ecs_task",
      "image": "${aws_ecr_repository.prod_ecr_repo.repository_url}",
      "essential": true,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 5000,
          "hostPort": 5000
        }
      ],
      "memory": 512,
      "cpu": 256
    }
  ]
  DEFINITION
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"] # use Fargate as the launch type
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"    # add the AWS VPN network mode as this is required for Fargate
  memory                   = 512         # Specify the memory the container requires
  cpu                      = 256         # Specify the CPU the container requires
  execution_role_arn       = "${aws_iam_role.ecsTaskExecutionRole.arn}"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ecsTaskExecutionRole" {
  name               = "ecsTaskExecutionRole"
  assume_role_policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role_policy.json}"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_role_policy" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecsTaskExecutionRole_policy" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.ecsTaskExecutionRole.name}"
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy"
}

resource "aws_default_vpc" "default_vpc" {
}

# Provide references to your default subnets
resource "aws_default_subnet" "default_subnet_a" {
  # Use your own region here but reference to subnet 1a
  availability_zone = "eu-west-2a"
}

resource "aws_default_subnet" "default_subnet_b" {
  # Use your own region here but reference to subnet 1b
  availability_zone = "eu-west-2b"
}

resource "aws_alb" "application_load_balancer" {
  name               = "load-balancer-dev" 
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  subnets = [ # Referencing the default subnets
    "${aws_default_subnet.default_subnet_a.id}",
    "${aws_default_subnet.default_subnet_b.id}"
  ]
  # security group
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.load_balancer_security_group.id}"]


}


resource "aws_security_group" "load_balancer_security_group" {
  ingress {
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"] # Allow traffic in from all sources
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "target_group" {
  name        = "target-group"
  port        = 80
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  target_type = "ip"
  vpc_id      = "${aws_default_vpc.default_vpc.id}" # default VPC
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "listener" {
  load_balancer_arn = "${aws_alb.application_load_balancer.arn}" #  load balancer
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"
  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = "${aws_lb_target_group.target_group.arn}" # target group
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "app_service" {
  name            = "app-first-service"     # Name the service
  cluster         = "${aws_ecs_cluster.prod_ecs_cluster.id}"   # Reference the created Cluster
  task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.prod_ecs_task.arn}" # Reference the task that the service will spin up
  launch_type     = "FARGATE"
  desired_count   = 3 # Set up the number of containers to 3

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = "${aws_lb_target_group.target_group.arn}" # Reference the target group
    container_name   = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.prod_ecs_task.family}"
    container_port   = 5000 # Specify the container port
  }

  network_configuration {
    subnets          = ["${aws_default_subnet.default_subnet_a.id}", "${aws_default_subnet.default_subnet_b.id}"]
    assign_public_ip = true     # Provide the containers with public IPs
    security_groups  = ["${aws_security_group.service_security_group.id}"] # Set up the security group
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "service_security_group" {
  ingress {
    from_port = 0
    to_port   = 0
    protocol  = "-1"
    # Only allowing traffic in from the load balancer security group
    security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.load_balancer_security_group.id}"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

output "app_url" {
  value = aws_alb.application_load_balancer.dns_name
}
```

When I visit the load balancer i get a 504 the first time and then consecutive 503's. If i look at the ECS console, I see a bunch of failed deployments, but no clear reason as to why. What would be a good way to start investigating this?

Comment: If you dig through the console, you can find the failure reason for why the task failed to deploy. Start there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the `aws_lb_target_group` resource's port to `5000`. That needs to match the port that the target is listening for traffic on.

Comment: After setting the resource "aws_lb_target_group" "target_group" port to 5000, the error still persists..

Comment: @Bowis OK do the container logs show any issues? Does the Target group show the container as health or unhealthy? What about the failure reason in the ECS console?